# Need to customize "jquery.dataTables.js" table with "View all" link

Tags: pagination, datatables

I need a help for jquery.dataTables.js

Here is my specific requirement.  Initially the table showing 10 rows.  This is good.  But I want to add one additional link called "View all".  When I clicks on that, entire rows should get showed.  How can I?

Does anybody knows?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by modifying the datatable's [lengthMenu option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/lengthMenu) to be something like

```
[[10, 25, -1], [10, 25, "All"]]
```

The elements of the first array dictate how many entries will be displayed per page ("-1" means "all"), the elements of the second are what will be shown to the user.

Note that this adds the "view all" option to the "[x] entries per page" dropdown, not as a separate link somewhere else in the table - I'm not sure from your question if it matters exactly *where* the "view all" option is.